# detect when a tabBar item is pressed via UITabBarController from App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I know this question has been asked a few times, but I am still stuck on the case when I have my `UITabBarController` in my `AppDelegate` class and viewControllers are set there only as

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = 
     @[aboutUsNavController,myProfileNavController,
      projectsListNavController, feedsNavController,homeViewController];
```

Now what I want is to perform a task at the tap of TabBar item `feedsNavController` **not in** `viewWillAppear` (because it is pushing a `detailView` via `navigationController` ).

I have set delegate in the same class to perform a `UITabBarController` delegate method:

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = 
         (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

But
 `-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` only works when I switch the TabBar Item, **but not at the first time**?

Is there any way I can call `UITabBarDelegate` instead:

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

in order to get the reference when `tabBar item` is pressed?

Or any other approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured out the way to do it:

Actually `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method only gets called once that particular tab it loaded.

Therefore, I performed task `[self getFeedsFromServer];` in `viewDidLoad` (for first time), and then again in

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"Selected INDEX OF TAB-BAR ==> %i", tabBarController.selectedIndex);

    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 3) {
      [self getFeedsFromServer];
    }
}
```

Works as I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform task 1 time then ViewDidLoad is best for it. ViewWillAppear calls every time your ViewController get focused but ViewDidLoad is called just when you push that Controller on stack.

Comment: 'viewDidLoad' gets called only one time: true, but I want to call a web-service every time I press that particular `tabBar` item.

Comment: `viewWillAppear` did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'because it is pushing a detailView via navigationController' ? Your question is not so much clear.

But maybe this thing me help you by my understanding:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)theTabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController    
 {

        NSUInteger indexOfTab = [theTabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
        NSLog(@"Tab index = %u (%u)", indexOfTab);

    }
```

Comment: I have tried and explained that I have NavigationControllers set on `tabBarController.viewControllers`, so there is a tableView which pushes that particular view, i.e., I cannot perform my task on `viewWillAppear` because everytime it I `popToViewController` `viewWillAppear` will get called