# iOS tabBarController detect selected index in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, appdelegate

AppDelegate.h *****

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate,UITabBarDelegate>
```

AppDelegate.m *****

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)tabBarController.selectedIndex);
}
```

This method not work any idea ? 
I want to scroll top when click tab bar item
Help please :)

Comment: Please clarify "not work"? It's not being called at all? If so, did you set the delegate correctly? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536756/detect-when-a-tabbar-item-is-pressed-via-uitabbarcontroller-from-app-delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add this line in the viewDidLoad method of your first viewController :

```
self.tabBarController.delegate = ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate);
```