# How to detect which tab a user has opened?

Tags: ios, swift, tabs

I'm new to swift and started to program a simple application in xcode. The application has multiple tabs in which in the firs one the user enters some data and the data should show in another tab. However I'm not able to achieve this as I don't know how to update a screen with the new data. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use view controller's viewWillAppear() method which updates every tab changes or you can use delegate method of tabbarcontroller see "https://stackoverflow.com/a/20537986/3797226" 

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been stuck on this for a while but your solution works like a charm.